# Java error when simulation software is closed

Tags: 14.04, java

so I have been using Comsol on ubuntu 14.04 for a while now. Everytime I close the software, a java error shows up. I tried updating java, reinstalling it but to no avail. Any help or advice is much appreciated. 
I have also added the error:

```
# A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment:
#
#  SIGSEGV[thread 139655972407040 also had an error]
 (0xb) at pc=0x00007f04318ec6e9, pid=20312, tid=139657766909696
#
# JRE version: 6.0_20-b02
# Java VM: Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (16.3-b01 mixed mode linux-amd64 )
# Problematic frame:
# C  [libcsgraphics_scene_common.so+0x1e06e9]  _ZN12flgraphics3d12SceneManagerD1Ev+0x299
#
# An error report file with more information is saved as:
# /home/shishir/hs_err_pid20312.log
#
# If you would like to submit a bug report, please visit:
#   http://java.sun.com/webapps/bugreport/crash.jsp
#
Aborted (core dumped)
```

Comment: What do you mean with "updating Java" Java 6 is a little bit old. [Edit] your question and add the content of the error log file `/home/shishir/hs_err_pid20312.log`.

Comment: @A.B. Hello again, the log file is too big to add as an edit. I'm adding it as a google doc instead.  [hs_err_pid20312.log](https://docs.google.com/document/d/18OXgcbD4X_oAGGKrhzuLncVUEtwDjT_HRhiX4rp4ca8/edit?usp=sharing)